# How to create a background service on linux with chef?

Tags: ubuntu, python, chef

I have a Python script that I'm executing using `screen` on an ubuntu host, and I want to turn that into a proper background service using a Chef recipe. The python script just starts up an SMTP server that discards all emails (a "black hole" server, useful for testing), and then calls python's `asyncore.loop()` to run forever.

How do I turn this into a chef recipe? I'm using the `cookbook_file` resource to upload my python script, and I know I need to use the `service` [resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_service.html) to start the service, but I'm not sure how to actually *create* the service to begin with. Do I need to write a file to `/etc/init.d` or `/etc/systemd` to create the service at the OS level, or is there some Chef recipe/resource I can call to create a background service for me, with a given command?

I'm using Chef *11.18.12* and can't upgrade, so that rules out some cookbooks (like [runit](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/runit)) that require 12+. The host OS is Ubuntu `14.04.3`.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
include_recipe 'apt'
include_recipe 'python'

# the python script to run as a background service    
cookbook_file '/usr/local/bin/smtp_server_blackhole.py' do
  source 'smtp_blackhole_server.py'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0755'
end

# the init.d file which defines the service? Not sure about this part...
cookbook_file "init.d_smtp_server_blackhole" do
    path "/etc/init.d/smtp_server_blackhole.py"
    source "init.d_smtp_server_blackhole"
    owner "root"
    group "root"
    mode "0755"
end

service "smtp_blackhole_server.py" do
  # this doesn't work, because the command doesn't reference an existing service?
  start_command 'python /usr/local/bin/smtp_blackhole_server.py -c bounce'
  action [ :enable, :start ]

  # I think I need to do something like this, to wait for the init.d file to be written
  subscribes :restart, "cookbook_file[init.d_smtp_server_blackhole]", :immediately
end
```

### Potential Solutions

1. [daemontools](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/daemontools) is a LWRP that allows you to create a service using a template file for the run command. However, it hasn't been updated in a couple of years, and it requires that you set up the `svscan` service for the "appropriate init system".
2. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603109/how-to-make-a-python-script-run-like-a-service-or-daemon-in-linux) has some good answers for how to write a Python daemon service using various code samples and Python libraries (e.g. [python-daemon](https://github.com/serverdensity/python-daemon) and [daemonize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/daemonize)), but it doesn't cover how to execute the OS commands in an idempotent way within a chef recipe.
3. https://github.com/poise/poise-service looks like what I need, but it doesn't support Chef 11.18, since poise 2.0 requires chef 12+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ubuntu 14.04 you would want to start with Upstart most likely since that's the system init framework. Check out the upstart Erb template in poise-service to see how to set things up or check out the Upstart Cookbook from Canonical. If you want to use something other than Upstary I would recommend Supervisord both for its simplicity and because it is popular in the Python community.